# Finding limit behavior of differential equation without solving it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Given:
$$
h' = \begin{bmatrix}-1&-4\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}h + \begin{bmatrix}0\\5\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am required to determine the limit of h(t) as t approaches infinity **without** solving for the differential equation. My take is that even without solving this or knowing what h(t) is, knowing that the constant matrix A has imaginary eigen values with a=--1 in a+ib, we know that the limit will go to zero for all t-related terms, leaving the constant in x(t) which is [0; 5] as t approaches infinity. This is assuming that the general solution to h' = Ah + B is as follows:

$$h(t) = c_{1}e^{\lambda t}\begin{bmatrix}
 & \\ 
 & 
\end{bmatrix}+c_{2}e^{\lambda t}\begin{bmatrix}
 & \\ 
 & 
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
 5\end{bmatrix}$$

But I'm not sure if that's true.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, both eigenvalues have negative real part, since the trace and discriminant are both negative real numbers.

That means any solution to the homogeneous equation goes to zero. Thus you can find the limit as $t \to \infty$ by finding any particular solution you want. You may guess that there is a solution with $h' \equiv 0$, which turns out to be correct, so you are left to solve the linear algebraic system

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -4 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} h + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

to find this particular solution.

Comment: So does the limit go to B in h'=Ah+B (which is [0;5]) or towards particular solutions of the system?

Comment: @HannahB It doesn't go to the same value as the constant forcing vector. It goes to the unique steady state solution.